# ListView isn't parsed from JSON Array / Adapter Values as expected

Tags: android, json, listview

I know I've overlooked something minor here - but I can't seem to populate my list view using the JSON data I've managed to parse out - I've debugged it and I have data for all my strings - but for some reason the listView isn't populating and I'm not sure what I've overlooked:

### Source:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r
                        .readLine()) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject cO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String value1 = cO.getString("field1");

                    JSONObject oC = cO.getJSONObject("itema");
                    String value2 = oC.getString("field2");

                    JSONObject oA = oC.getJSONObject("itemb");
                    String value3 = oA.getString("field3");

                    final JSONAdapter jSONAdapter;
                    jSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(Example.this, jsonArray);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final ListView list;
                            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                            list.setAdapter(jSONAdapter);

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the jsonArray if you're setting the jsonArray as parameter for the JSONAdapter anyway? Shouldn't you be doing something with `sha`, `commitmessage` and  `authorname`?

Comment: I need help adding those items to the list

Comment: something along the lines of list.append but I'm not quite sure

Comment: So the list should have entries like this: `authorname + " " + sha + " - " + message` or something?

Comment: yes - exactly correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do the following.

First: `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` runs on the main thread, and you should use that instead. Let `doInBackground` return a `List<String>`

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<String>> {
    private String url;

    public MyAsyncTask(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
            .openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r
                    .readLine()) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject cO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String value1 = cO.getString("field1");

                    JSONObject oC = cO.getJSONObject("itema");
                    String value2 = oC.getString("field2");

                    JSONObject oA = oC.getJSONObject("itemb");
                    String value3 = oA.getString("field3");

                //format how you want to output each row;
                result.add(value1 + " " + value2 + " - " + value3); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Example.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This means the signature of your `AsyncTask` becomes `AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>` if i'm not mistaken. What actually happens is this: you extract the strings per entry in the jsonarray. Then you add it to your list. The you return the list, and it is passed into the `onPostExecute(List<String>)`. Then, we find the listview, create an `ArrayAdapter<String>`, and set `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as the layout each String is projected on, and we also set the list as the thing the arrayadapter should be projecting.

After that, we set the adapter.

EDIT: The signature of the asynctask should be

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, List<String>> {
    public List<String> doInBackground(Void...args);
    public void onPostExecute(List<String> list);
}
```

And to fix your fatal error:

1. return `list`, not null.
2. delete your empty `doInBackground(Void...args)` method
3. change `doInBackgorund(String...args)` to `doInBackground(Void...args)`

Or the full code

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, List<String>> {
    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
    String url = "https://example.com";

    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
            .openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r
                    .readLine()) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject cO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String value1 = cO.getString("field1");

                    JSONObject oC = cO.getJSONObject("itema");
                    String value2 = oC.getString("field2");

                    JSONObject oA = oC.getJSONObject("itemb");
                    String value3 = oA.getString("field3");

                //format how you want to output each row;
                result.add(value1 + " " + value2 + " - " + value3);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Example.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can now copy/paste the code. Make sure you read it, so you know what's happening.

Comment: Thanks! That worked -  btw can you remove your edit that contains my paste bin data? It has the urls and some of the code Im working with and I didnt really want them up on here